# "How are Mike and Chris?" vs. "How is Mike and Chris?"

Tags: grammatical-number, conjunctions, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, compound-subjects

Which one of the following is correct?  I think the first, but many people use the second as well.

1. How are Mike and Chris?
2. How is Mike and Chris?

Comment: The first. The second is a failure of the speaker to anticipate the compound subject.

Comment: The second one is common, because it contracts well and backwards agreement is normally ignored. _How's Mike and Chris?_ works just fine, introduces no ambiguity, saves one syllable as well as probly a hundred lines of sloppy code for parsing agreement.

Comment: Also, this is not a collective noun, is it?

Comment: @recognizer - pls assume they are two different folks,,

Comment: The title of the post says collective noun, but there aren't any in your example.

Comment: @Chellspecker - Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is correct.

In general, the second would not be considered correct grammar.  But it can be meaningful English, and from that point of view, correct.

The second can be correct in that sense, if what is meant by "*Mike & Chris*" is the couple (pair).  The second then has the meaning of asking about the status of that couple, in other words, asking about the relationship between Mike and Chris.

In this context, "*How is Mike & Chris*" is really an informal, shortened way of asking "*How is the thing that folks refer to as 'Mike & Chris' doing these days?*"

Such a treatment can be ironic, humorous, or mean.  A stronger form of mockery might be "*How is the Mike-and-Chris show, these days*"?

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct. The second is improper grammar in that a singular verb is used with a compound subject.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first is correct. There are cases where an "X & Y" example would be considered singular, for example when the X & Y construction is the name of a business or product.

"Is Crate & Barrel having a sale this week?"

"Ben & Jerry's is the best ice-cream."

"Black & Decker makes the best automatic bread machine."